# Apache Camel Spring Boot Health Check exposure-level

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, health-check

I am using Apache Camel Spring boot(3.1.2), Camel Version is 4.0.0. Health check is enabled, it's working, but /health always return UP/DOWN, there is no details, even I set the exposure level to full:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: "/"
      exposure:
        include: health,info,loggers,camelroutes
    probes:
      enabled: true
    health:
      show-details: always
  health:
    livenessState:
      enabled: true
    readinessState:
      enabled: true

camel:
  springboot:
    route-controller-supervise-enabled: true
    route-controller-back-off-max-attempts: 10
  health:
    enabled: true
    # level of details exposed by camel-health check (full, default, or oneline)
    exposure-level: full
    producers-enabled: true
    registry-enabled: true
    consumers-enabled: true
    routes-enabled: true
```

When setting the exposure level to full, it should show more details.

Comment: what dependencies have you added in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong, you've set `endpoints` but the path should be `management.endpoint.health.show-details`.